# Online shop interacting with database, updating cart and instantiating products

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm new to programming web sites (and so on the relationship between program and database) and I have encountered a problem.

I'm creating an online web shop that interacts and saves every info on a database.

The problem comes up regarding the shopping cart: I want that when a user adds a product in the cart, he can logout and when he logs in again he should find the cart unaltered, so I have a product as an object `Product` that has a `int productID` that is unique in the database.

I have a package DAO that interacts with the database, and there is this method:

```
/**
 * Queries the database in search of the shopping cart of the indicated user
 * @param userMail indicates the user from which take the shopping cart
 * @return the Shopping Cart of the user
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException if an error occurs with the connection to the database
 */
public static ShoppingCart getShoppingCartFromDatabase(String userMail) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    ShoppingCart updatedCart = new ShoppingCart(userMail);

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USERNAME, JDBC_PASSWORD)){

        try (PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM  " + TABLE_NAME + " "
                + "WHERE user = ?")) {
            pst.clearParameters();

            pst.setString(1, userMail);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                String userMail = rs.getString("user");
                int IDProduct = rs.getInt("product");
                int npieces = rs.getInt("npieces");

                //HERE THE PROBLEM
                updatedCart.addToCart(IDProduct, npieces);

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Errorin query: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error in connection: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return updatedCart;

}
```

The class `ShoppingCart`:

```
public class ShoppingCart {

    private final String userMail;
    private final List<ProductInCart> productsInCart;

    /**
     * Constructor of ShoppingCart.
     * It creates a new ProductInCart item and assigns it to the list of ShoppingCart
     * @param mail is the mail of the user, that is the owner of the shopping cart
     */
    public ShoppingCart(String mail){

        this.userMail = mail;
        this.productsInCart = new ArrayList<ProductInCart>();

    }

    //other methods, such as get and set etc

}
```

And the class `ProductInCart`:

```
public class ProductInCart{

    private final Product product;
    private int numberOfProducts;

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     * @param product Product to be added
     * @param num Number of that item in the cart
     */
    public ProductInCart(Product product, int num){
        this.product = product;
        this.numberOfProducts = num;
    }

    //Other methods such as get and set, etc

}
```

The problem is that the method `public void addToCart(Product product, int num)` adds a product of type `Product` and I don't know how to get from the ID of the product to the product itself, other than creating again locally the product in `getShoppingCartFromDatabase` method.

The `addToCart` method:

```
/**
* Adds multiple items of a new product in the cart
* @param product added in cart
* @param num number of items of that product
* @throws ClassNotFoundException if an error occurs with the connection to the database
* @see ShoppingCartDAO#addOneItem(String, ProductInCart)
*/
public void addToCart(Product product, int num) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    ProductInCart added = new ProductInCart(product, num);
    this.productInCart.add(added);
    ShoppingCartDAO.addOneItem(this.userMail, added);
}
```

The method `ShoppingCartDAO.addOneItem(String, Product)` adds a row in the table of the `cart(IDProduct, IDUser, nPieces)` in the database, and `PK(IDProduct, IDUser)`.

This is my solution (or better, the explanation of my solution because all the code would be very large).

Premise: the products stored are of three types, `Product`, `ProfessionalProduct` and `ScholasticProduct`, both extend `Product`.

My solution is that in method `getShoppingCartFromDatabase(String userMail, User user)` I execute a query that queries the database (table `cart`) with the `userMail` (that is the ID of the user) and puts in a `ResultSet` all the products (or rather their IDs) and the number of items.

When I scan the `ResultSet`, I first clean the cart of the user, deleting the cart of that user in the database (I have a temporary copy in `ResultSet`), and then I add the product in the new cart and in the database: `updatedCart.addToCart(ProductDAO.getFromDatabase(productID), nPieces);`

That method now works because `ProductDAO.getFromDatabase(productID)` returns a `Product`.
The method `ProductDAO.getFromDatabase(productID)` executes a query on the database looking for the product with the indicated ID, then it returns a new object of type `Product` (or `ProfessionalProduct` or `ScholasticProduct` based on an `int productType` that discriminates between the types and allows me to call the right constructor) that is created in that method.

My question is if there is a better solution, because mine seems a little bit complicated and prone to errors. I assume that an user can have up to ten or so products in the cart, so it's futile to talk about performances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### DAO

In general the creation of the database connection is extracted as a separate responsibility, either to a Library or into a `ConnectionFactory`. This allows you to then change anything about the Connection implementation without having to adjust it in every single DAO method:

```
public static ShoppingCart getShoppingCartFromDatabase(String userMail) {
    ShoppingCart updatedCart = new ShoppingCart(userMail);
    try (Connection con = ConnectionFactory.newConnection()) {
        // ...
```

I like very much that you're using try-with-resources, I'd drop the inner catch block though.

I also like that you're using a `PreparedStatement`. I like less that it's a `SELECT *`. In general `SELECT *` is discouraged because of the performance implications and it's unwanted ignorance of the table structure. Instead the columns selected should be properly enumerated:

```
private static final String CART_QUERY = "SELECT user, product, npieces FROM " 
     + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE user = ?";
// [...]

    try (PreparedStatement pst = con.perpareStatement(CART_QUERY)) {
       // ...
```

clearing the Parameters on a freshly instantiated PreparedStatement is a waste of CPU cycles, drop that :)

#### Design Problem

Regarding your design question: You're probably interested in a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT user, nproducts, product.name as pname, product.type as ptype
FROM {TABLE_NAME} 
JOIN {PRODUCT_TABLE} ON {TABLE_NAME}.product = {PRODUCT_TABLE}.id
```

This allows you to directly retrieve the product from the database

#### General

It's generally not a good idea to put everything in an application into the static context. That makes it hard to reduce coupling between components. Instead of that you should strive to remove the `static` keyword wherever possible and research **Dependency Injection**